# Android screen resolutions mess up my layout

Tags: android, python, kivy, python-2.x

I am developing a mobile application with Python and Kivy and I have it working with SQLite3 and that is all going good.

I was just designing the layout of it and I centered two TextInput boxes based on co-ordinates and it worked great on the PyCharm app tester. I then ported it to my android device and the boxes used the same co-ordinates but as the resolution was different, it ended up on a different parts of the screen.
I then tried this piece of code;

```
<Code@BoxLayout>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: .176, .196, .222
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
    idcode: id_input
    FloatLayout:
        TextInput:
            id: id_input
            font_size: '15sp'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1] + dp(10)
```

Only to be faced with this error;

```
BuilderException: Parser: File "/home/seandowney/PycharmProjects/SchoolShow/disocial.kv", line 45:
 ...
      43:            font_size: '15sp'
      44:            size_hint_y: None
 >>   45:            height: self.texture_size[1] + dp(10)
      46:
 ...
 AttributeError: 'TextInput' object has no attribute 'texture_size'
```

What I am looking to do is be able to set certain boxes, labels, buttons and TextInputs at certain locations on the screen and have them appear in the same location on every screen, not matter the resolution.
If anyone can offer any help, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not sure how to make the textinput grow to accommodate its text, but is this really what you actually want? I think you should describe what you're actually trying to achieve, not how you think it should be done, it may be that there's a much simpler way to use layouts to get there.

Comment: @inclement I have added to the bottom of the question, I hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the same location'? By proportion of the screen?

Comment: @inclement so that if I put the button in the bottom left corner. When the resolution changes, it shall remain in the bottom left corner.

Comment: Use the pos_hint property. e.g. `pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': 0}` means the bottom left. You can check the documentation for other tokens.

Comment: @inclement that will change depending on resolution though.

Comment: If that's not what you want, then you really need to explain some more. What specific parameter of the position do you want to remain invariant to changes of the screen size?

Comment: @inclement sorry if it was not clear. when I have the co-ordinates, let's say,  'x' : 15, 'y' : 15. and I test this on three different phones, the resolution will affect the size and the IT will appear different on each screen. I want it to stay in the same location.

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you want to be the same on each screen.

Comment: @inclement maybe device would be a better word than screen. I want it to appear in the same position for multiple devices besides changing position over resolution

Comment: But what is 'position'? We've established that it's not a proportional position on the screen as that's what pos_hint does, and your original question suggests that it's not a same precise pixel position (that's what you mean by 'coordinates'?), so what *do* you want to be  the same on each device? A real world distance like cm?

Comment: no. ok, look where your w key is on your key board and picture that a phone screen. now, if you make the keyboard smaller, the keys will stay in the same position? but instead the w jumps to where the g is. if I centre something I want it to stay in centre not matter resolution.